# How can I get a graphical representation of my dependencies with Spring.NET IoC?

Tags: c#, spring.net

I'm using Spring.NET's IoC container and everything has been working just fine....until now. Somehow, in one of our previous releases, we introduced a circular dependency. Since we use setter based injection as opposed to constructor based injection, Spring.NET just kept humming along fine, but the behavior of our app changed.

Now I have a solution with a hundred or so components, and somewhere in that pile of components exists a circular dependency, which I now need to find.

Are there any tools that can take my Spring.NET config files and give me a graphical picture of my components and their dependencies?

Comment: Good question. AFAIK there isn't such a tool for spring.net specifically. Have you tried to use a regular memory profiler on a fully loaded spring context?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm confused how a memory profiler would help me?

Comment: Added an answer on how you _could_ do this with a memory profiler ... theoretically that is; I doubt whether you'll be able to pull this of with your large context.

Comment: A more interesting approach is the one on [this thread](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?4158-Visualising-object-relationships&highlight=dependency+graph) on the springframework forum. You might be able to hack a test application that finds circular references using the approach outlined there.

Comment: I removed my answer that demonstrated the use of a memory profiler; I don't consider it to be of much help.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there isn't such a tool available, although there is one for spring for Java. 
This [thread on the spring.net forum](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?4158-Visualising-object-relationships&highlight=dependency+graph)
 discusses the issue and proposes a solution.
I made a quick-and-dirty proof of concept based on Thomas Darimont's approach using [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/).

For the following configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

  <object id="a1" type="q7446068.ClassA, q7446068" >
    <property name="MyOtherA" ref="a2" />
  </object>

  <object id="a2" type="q7446068.ClassA, q7446068" >
    <property name="MyOtherA" ref="a1" />
  </object>

  <object id="a3" type="q7446068.ClassA, q7446068" />

</objects>
```

I was able to create the following dot file:

```
digraph G {
    0 [label="a1"];
    1 [label="a2"];
    2 [label="a3"];
    0 -> 1 [];
    1 -> 0 [];
}
```

[image: using graphviz to make a trivial picture]

Which shows the circular dependency.

The code is available [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/1223983).

Comment: How did you generate that image? Did you just do that by hand? Seems like GraphViz should be able to do that.

Comment: I used dot, it comes with the graphviz distributable. You can also use [zgrviewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html) to view dot files. You need graphviz to use zgrviewer.

Comment: Graphviz for windows can be found at http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php, but you were probably aware of that.